# newsletter popup form, get confirmation in the same window

Tags: javascript, php

I have a popup form but:
 - the validation is also a popup and dosnt appear messages
 - after submit I would like to get confirmation message in the same popup

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#newsletter').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$('#modal-content').popUpWindow({
action: "open", 
modal: true, 
size: "large", 
buttons: [{
text: "x",
click: function () {
this.close();
}
}]
});
});

});
</script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var mailChk =/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
function checkSubscribe()
{
    if($("#snume").val()==''){
        $("#msg").html("sdfsdfsfsfsdf");
        $("#snume").focus();
        return false;
    }if($("#semail").val()==''){
        $("#msg").html("sdfsdfsfs");
        $("#semail").focus();
        return false;
    } if($("#semail").val()!='' && !mailChk.test($("#semail").val())){
        $("#msg").html("sfsdfsfsfd");
        $("#semail").focus();
        return false;
    }
}

</script>
```

and the form

```
<div id="modal-content" class="pop-up-display-content">
<h4>Abonare la newsletter</h4>
<p>Acum te poti abona la newsletter folosind formularul de mai jos.</p>
<?
if(isset($_POST['newsll']))
    {
        skjdklasjdlka
    }
?>
<form action="<?=basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<?=$msg?>
<input type="text" name="snume" class="k8-frm-input" id="snume" placeholder="Nume si prenume"/><br/>
<input type="text" name="semail" class="k8-frm-input" id="semail" placeholder="Email"/><br/>
      <input type="submit" name="newsll" value="submit" id="normal" class="btn k8-btn" onclick="return checkSubscribe()"/>
</form>
</div>
```

After submit, I get message in the form, if I click again the popup button, I see the message from last submit. But I would like to stay open popup and display message.

And after I close the popup, I would like not to see the last message.

And also, I need the validation to display somewhere... The validation is working because I cant submit form, but no messages appears.

Thanks